# Python object instantiation

Tags: python, object, instantiation

I am very new to python and need some help with instantiating an object. The python interpreter is giving me trouble when instantiating an object of a class I defined. There are two classes, `BTNode` and `BST` (which are stored in files `bst_node.py` and `bst.py` respectively):

```
# file: bst_node.py

class BTNode:

    """a binary search tree node implementation"""

    def ___init___(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left is None
        self.right is None
        self.parent is None

    def ___init___(self, value, left, right, parent):
        """set the parameters to corresponding class members"""
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.parent = parent

    def is_leaf(self):
        """check whether this node is a leaf"""
        if self.left.value is None and self.right.value is None:
            return True 
        return False
```

---

```
# file: bst.py

from bst_node import *

class BST:

    """a binary search tree implementation"""
    def ___init___(self, value):
        self.root = BTNode(value)

    def insert(self, curRoot, newValue):
        if curRoot.is_leaf():
            if newValue < curRoot.value:
                newNode = BTNode(newValue, None, None, curRoot)
                curRoot.left = newNode
            else:
                newNode = BTNode(newValue, None, None, curRoot)
                curRoot.right = newNode
        else:
            if newValue < curRoot.value:
                self.insert(curRoot.left, newValue)
            else:
                self.insert(curRoot.right, newValue)
```

So, in the interpreter I do:

```
import bst as b
t1 = b.BST(8)
```

and I get an error which says that this `constructor takes no arguments`

The constructor clearly takes an argument `value` so what is going wrong here? How can I fix this error?

Thanks, all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not your question but unless I'm mistaken you'll run into a problem with the lines like `self.left is none` because `is` compares, and will either be `True` or `False`.  Use `self.left = None` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the number of underscores problem, you should replace

```
def ___init___(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.left is None
    self.right is None
    self.parent is None

def ___init___(self, value, left, right, parent):
    """set the parameters to corresponding class members"""
    self.value = value
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    self.parent = parent
```

with

```
def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None, parent=None):
    """set the parameters to corresponding class members"""
    self.value = value
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    self.parent = parent
```

Because as @Moshe points out, you can't overload functions, you should use default arguments insted.

Answer (score 5):

The first issue is that you called your functions `___init___` instead of `__init__`. All of the 'special methods' use two underscores.

A second issue in this code is that in `BTNode` you redefined `__init__`. You can't overload functions in python. When you reclare `__init__` you effectively deleted the first constructor.

A third issue is your usage of `is`. `is` is an operator that checks whether two objects are exactly the same and returns `True` or `False`. In the constructor, you have a few `self.left is None` is examining the value of `self.left` (which wasn't declared yet), and examining whether or not it is `None`. To set it, use `=` as follows:`self.left = None`

To fix the second and third issue you should use [default argument values](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values). For example:

`def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None, parent=None):`

Answer (score 2):

Changing `___init___` to `__init__` should fix it. (2 underscores vs 3)